# MediaPlayer setLooping(true) freezing my phone

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, sony-xperia

I want to loop a music in my app so I use the following code:

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);
mediaPlayer.setVolume(8f, 8f);
mediaPlayer.start();
mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
```

I've try to start and then setLooping, the problem still there.

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);
mediaPlayer.setVolume(8f, 8f);
mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

But when the music ends it don't restart and my app slows rapidly until total freeze, but there is no crash.
If I look at the log there is a huge succession of :

```
MediaPlayer_Java: MEDIA_PAUSED
MediaPlayer_Java: MEDIA_STARTED
```

My phone is a Xperia M4 Aqua.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: You're starting then setting it to loop.

Comment: Thank you but even if I put setLooping() after start() it doesn't work ...

Comment: Where did you write that piece of code? In onCreate()? Make sure that it is not inside a while loop or for loop blocks.

Comment: @HusseinElFeky yes directly on the onCreate() of an all clean new app.

Answer (score 1):

```
mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
```

is before start media player

Comment: @sypotu use this code Uri mediaUri = createUri(context, R.raw.media); // Audiofile in raw folder
Mediaplayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mPlayer.setDataSource(context, mediaUri);
mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mPlayer.prepare();

mPlayer.setLooping(true);

mPlayer.start();